# How do I separate these two functions?

Tags: ios, swift, function, firebase, swift3

Right now when I click on the pick image action I pick an image and it goes directly to the database as soon as the image picker closes. How do I make it two different functions so that one button picks an image and the other uploads it?

```
@IBAction func pickImage(_ sender: Any) {


    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

    image.allowsEditing = false

    self.present(image, animated: true)
    {
        //after its completed
    }


@objc(imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        myImageView.image = image

    }
    else
    {
        //error
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(NSUUID().uuidString)/image.png")
    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myImageView.image!){

        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion:
            {
                (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error")
                    return
                }

                else {

                    let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                    self.ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Title": self.titleText.text,"Article": self.mainText.text, "Author": self.authorText.text, "Date": self.dateText.text,  "Download URL": (downloadURL)])

             }                
        }                  
        )
    }
```

Comment: Update your question with your attempt to split the functionality and use two buttons. Clearly explain what troubles you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your current code it looks like that you have added delegate method of `UIImagePickerController` inside your `pickImage` button action this is wrong delegate method should also be added as your other class instance method means it must be outside of that `pickImage` button.

```
@IBAction func pickImage(_ sender: Any) {

    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false

    self.present(image, animated: true)
}

//Add didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo here
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        myImageView.image = image            
    }
    else {
        //error
    }        
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now add new button action `uploadImage` and add the code of `FIRStorage` with it. After that simply bind this action with your upload button.

```
@IBAction func uploadImage(_ sender: Any) {

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(NSUUID().uuidString)/image.png")
    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myImageView.image!){

        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
                return
            }                        
            else {                     
                let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                self.ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Title": self.titleText.text,"Article": self.mainText.text, "Author": self.authorText.text, "Date": self.dateText.text,  "Download URL": (downloadURL)])                        
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: can you help me with this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739572/how-do-i-add-an-image-that-may-or-may-not-be-there-to-firebase-storage